# In R, how can i use package"regular expression" or removing the unmatched files in two folders

Tags: r, regex

I have two folders. The first folder(post) has 7 files “abc.csv, bcc.csv, cdd.csv, dgg.csv, efg.csv, fgg.csv, gda.csv”. The second folder(comment) has 4 files “abc_comment.csv, bcc_comment.csv, efg_comment.csv, fgg_comment.csv”.

I want to read only the file that the first part in file name is same.
For example, abc.csv and abc_comment.csv are same in the first part but 3 files (cdd.csv, dgg.csv, fgg.csv) have no same comment.csv file. So, in second folder, file_lists are removed.

I have no idea for doing this and maybe I think that I need to use package“regex”.

Below is my basic code, and how can I add the code?

```
    post_dir <- c:/post/
    comment_dir <- c:/comment/
    post <- list.files(post_dir)
    comment <- list.files(comment_dir)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily without the knowledge of complex regex with stringr and R subsetting

```r
library(tidyverse)

fake_post <- c('abc.csv',' bcc.csv', 'cdd.csv', 'dgg.csv', 'efg.csv', 'fgg.csv', 'gda.csv')

fake_comment <- c('abc_comment.csv', 'bcc_comment.csv', 'efg_comment.csv', 'fgg_comment.csv')


# Strip extension

fake_post2 <- fake_post %>% str_remove('.csv')

# Strip comment and extension
fake_comment2 <- fake_comment %>% str_remove('_comment.csv')

fake_post[fake_post2 %in% fake_comment2]
#> [1] "abc.csv" "efg.csv" "fgg.csv"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I want to read the file. so I think that if get rid of '_comment.csv' I cannot read the csv file using read.csv. could you recommend the other method?

Comment: You still have the file name, you can then do something like map(fake_post[fake_post2 %in% fake_comment2],read_csv)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

1. Use for loop to change target pattern.
2. we get target file paths :)
3. Read files into R.
4. Assign the file names as object names.

```
post_dir <- c:/post/
comment_dir <- c:/comment/
post <- c('abc.csv',' bcc.csv', 'cdd.csv', 'dgg.csv', 'efg.csv', 'fgg.csv', 'gda.csv')

target<-gsub("\\.csv","",post)
#[1] "abc"  " bcc" "cdd"  "dgg"  "efg"  "fgg"  "gda" 

for (i in target){
assign(i,read.csv(list.files(post_dir,pattern=i,full.names = T)))

name<-paste0(i,"_comment") 
assign(name,read.csv(list.files(comment_dir,pattern=i,full.names = T)))

}
```